# Как и где отключить запрет на проверку POST запроса со стороннего сайта в YII2 на определённой странице

Tags: yii2

Как и где отключить запрет на проверку POST запроса со стороннего сайта в YII2 на определённой странице?

Сейчас код ошибки 400.

Comment: не уверен что у вас проблема именно с удаленным запросом т.к. 400 скорее непонимание от сервера что ты от него хочешь,  но скорее всего надо просто отключить CSRF проверку. Если с того же домена этот запрос работает

Comment: Возможно, а как отключить CSRF проверку в контролере в самой экшене?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28526873/disable-csrf-validation-for-individual-actions-in-yii2 тут написано

Comment: Действительно сработало. Спасибо :)